# Enable tunneling of connections web logic server

Tags: weblogic12c

I have web logic server installed and I want to enable tunneling of connections on it. I cannot use http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/servers.html#Configuring_HTTP_Protocol because I have just access from the command line.

Please, there a way to do that from command line?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

After setting your environment (. wlserver/server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh on linux) the following should do the trick so long as you supply the proper values for $url, $username and $password.

java weblogic.Admin -url $url -username $username -password $password SET -type Server -property TunnelingEnabled true